# what encoding is b'' using by default in python?

Tags: python

when i use `b''` to convert string to bytes, I don't have to think about encoding type.

However if the string contains variable, for example `s = f'this is {x}'`, I can't convert s to bytes with `b''`. I must use `bytes()` but then I have to think about encoding type.

Could someone please confirm my understanding above? and if it's correct, what encoding is `b''` using by default?

Comment: `b''` is not used to convert string to bytes. That is the notation for writing a *bytes literal*. No encoding is used, you can put arbitrary bytes, it's just that printable ascii characters correspond to their ascii value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b'...'` *always* uses ASCII, because only (certain) ASCII characters are allowed in `bytes` literals. In such a literal, an ASCII character represents its ASCII value as a byte. `b'a'` and `b'\x61'`, for example, are equivalent, producing the same value as `bytes([0x61])`.

You aren't converting `str` values to `bytes` values; there is just overlap between the characters that can appear in each.